# Quitar ordenar según la columna datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatable

Estoy intentando que mi tabla que utilizo datatable desactive la opcion de ordenar por columnas.

He intentado esto pero no funciona

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tablaPlatos').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange" : false,
        "pageLength": 50,
        "orderable": false
    })
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tablaPlatos').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange" : false,
        "pageLength": 50,
        "columnDefs": [
          { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 },//ocultar para columna 0
          { "orderable": false, "targets": 1 },//ocultar para columna 1
          //`Asi para cada columna`...
        ],
    })
} );
```